# Are multiple wives allowed in israel

Tags: marriage

I know several people who have come from the Arabic countries like Syria and Saudi, and have multiple wives. Is it allowed to legally have multiple wives in any country today, or do they only consider a single marriage certificate?

Comment: Hi Ess Kay. The answer to your question is that, no it is not legal. However, this question is going to be closed as off-topic because questions about the State of Israel are not on topic here. Questions should be about Judaism.

Comment: @Daniel To be clear: questions about the State of Israel *and not about Judaism* are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so simple. Marriage is administered by individual faith groups in Israel. I don't know how it's handled for Muslims there.

For Jews arriving from polygamous countries, my understanding is that decades ago the Israeli rabbinate would make exceptions, but they're approaching the point where they'd actually tell a Yemeni immigrant -- "you have to choose one of your two wives."

Comment: thanks.  the rest of the people here are hypothetical thinkers,  usless for real questions (at least the ones who voted it down) .  Toda raba